Pytorch index consume huge amount of time
I defined following function for some simple matrix operations. I found that when cs is fixed, and X_cuda (a (N,D) matrix) is large,
function "cnfg = cs_cuda[candidate_ind, :] "consumes the majority of the time, it consumes more time than all rest of the operations.
Then I profiled this function, and I found that:
aten::_local_scalar_dense: This operation is taking up 97.99% of the CPU time.
Is anyone know why this happens
def seleval_GPU(cs):
# Convert data to PyTorch tensors
N,D = X_cuda.shape
cs_cuda = cs.cuda()

M = cs_cuda.size(0)


# Convert indices_list to a tensor
A_chunk = X_cuda[cs_cuda].float() #(M, D, D)

b_chunk = torch.ones(M, D, 1, device='cuda')

ws = torch.linalg.solve(A_chunk, b_chunk) # (M, D, 1)    

# convert to float16
ws = ws.squeeze(-1) #(M,D)

ones = torch.ones(M, 1).cuda()  #(M,1)

sign_dists=  torch.matmul(ws, X_cuda.T)-ones # (M,N)

threshold = 1e-6
sign_dists[sign_dists.abs() < threshold] = 0

sign_vectors =  torch.sign(sign_dists)
# Use advanced indexing to set the elements at the specified indices to 0
# sign_vectors[torch.arange(M).unsqueeze(1), cs_cuda] = 0

sum_labelss = sign_vectors + t_cuda
lss_pos = torch.sum(sum_labelss == 0, dim=1, dtype=torch.int16) #size (M,)
lss_neg = N-D-lss_pos
best_lss = torch.stack((lss_pos, lss_neg), dim=1)
best_ls, min_index = torch.min(best_lss,dim=1)


candidate_loss, candidate_ind = torch.min(best_ls, dim=0)
candidate_ind = candidate_ind.cuda()  # Ensure candidate_ind is on GPU

start = time.perf_counter()
cnfg = cs_cuda[candidate_ind, :]  # Accessing large tensor on GPU
end = time.perf_counter()
print(f'you spend {end-start} time for this block')

best_cnfg = (cnfg, candidate_loss)
return best_cnfg


Try to use torch.gather and report the result back? It's hard to debug without minimal reproducible example.
